# Get deep object along with parent

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Below is the sample data(Hierarchical data) I want to only that array of object which has `IsChecked = true` and also all its children with condition `isChecked =true`.

```
$scope.treedData = [{
        "id": "1",
        "text": "Women",
        "parentId": null,
        "IsChecked": true,
        "children": [{
            "id": "4",
            "text": "Jeans",
            "parentId": "1",
            "IsChecked": true,
            "children": [
                { "id": "5", "text": "Jeans child", "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": true, "children": [] },
                { "id": "6", "text": "Jeans child child", "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": false, "children": [] }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "Men",
        "parentId": null,
        "IsChecked": false,
        "children": [{ "id": "10", "text": "Sweatshirts", "parentId": "2", "IsChecked": false, "children": [] }]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "text": "Kids",
        "parentId": null,
        "IsChecked": true,
        "children": [{ "id": "12", "text": "Toys", "parentId": "3", "IsChecked": false, "children": [] }]
    }
];
```

Comment: Note that the indenting in your object structure is misleading: node 4 is the parent of node 5. So even though node 5 has `IsChecked` as true, node 4 has not. What is your expected output?

Comment: Fixed the misleading indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for that, and use recursion to apply the filter to the children hierarchy as well:

```js
var treeData = [
  { "id": "1", "text": "Women", "parentId": null, "IsChecked": true,
   "children": [
     { "id": "4", "text": "Jeans",  "parentId": "1", "IsChecked": false, "children":[
       { "id": "5", "text": "Jeans child",  "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": true, "children":[]  },
       { "id": "6", "text": "Jeans child child",  "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": false, "children":[]  }
     ]  }]
  },
  { "id": "2", "text": "Men", "parentId": null,  "IsChecked": false,
   "children": [{ "id": "10", "text": "Sweatshirts", "parentId": "2", "IsChecked": false, "children":[]}]
  },
  {"id": "3", "text": "Kids", "parentId": null,  "IsChecked": true,
   "children": [{ "id": "12", "text": "Toys", "parentId": "3", "IsChecked": false, "children":[] }]
  }
];

checkedTreeData = treeData.reduce(function checkedOnly (acc, obj) {
  return obj.IsChecked 
    ? acc.concat(Object.assign({}, obj, { children: obj.children.reduce(checkedOnly, []) }))
    : acc;
}, []);

console.log(checkedTreeData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NB: In JavaScript there is an unwritten rule to not use an initial capital letter for property names, so `IsChecked` would be with a lower case `i`: `isChecked`. Initial capital letters are commonly used for constructors (classes).

#### Alternative with `.filter()`

```js
function filterChecked(treeData) {
  return treeData.filter(obj => obj.IsChecked)
    .map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, obj.children ? 
                { children: filterChecked(obj.children) } : {}))
}

var treeData = [
  { "id": "1", "text": "Women", "parentId": null, "IsChecked": true,
   "children": [
     { "id": "4", "text": "Jeans",  "parentId": "1", "IsChecked": false, "children":[
       { "id": "5", "text": "Jeans child",  "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": true, "children":[]  },
       { "id": "6", "text": "Jeans child child",  "parentId": "4", "IsChecked": false, "children":[]  }
     ]  }]
  },
  { "id": "2", "text": "Men", "parentId": null,  "IsChecked": false,
   "children": [{ "id": "10", "text": "Sweatshirts", "parentId": "2", "IsChecked": false, "children":[]}]
  },
  {"id": "3", "text": "Kids", "parentId": null,  "IsChecked": true,
   "children": [{ "id": "12", "text": "Toys", "parentId": "3", "IsChecked": false, "children":[] }]
  }
];


console.log(filterChecked(treeData));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but while running the snippet I'm not getting any children for the filtered item. It is showing  "children": [], however we need to have all children which have `isChecked = true`

Comment: But those children have a parent with isChecked : false (id: 4)... so which will be the parent then? Maybe I misunderstood, but it would be helpful if you would add the expected output to your question.

Comment: @h_singh trincot is right, you should clarify the question, even stasovlas assumed something else in his answer. So the question is definitely not clear enough.

Comment: now I understand y you have that superman S on your head, thanks @trincot  :)

Answer (score 0):

use Lodash [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#filter) and [`_.every`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#every)

```
_.filter(treedData, function(item) {
    return _.every([
        item.IsChecked,
        _.every(item.children, 'IsChecked')
    ]);
});
```

if you also want to check condition of children of children you can do it recursively like

```
_.filter(treedData, function check(item) {
    return _.every([
        item.IsChecked,
        _.size(item.children) === 0 || _.every(item.children, check)
    ]);
});
```